# Incorrect change of class from "character" to "numeric"

Tags: r

I faced a problem. I need the last column (dat [, 11]) to be displayed as a number, then it will need to be sorted from smaller to larger.

This code works and changes to a numeric format, but the numbers there do not match the original data at all.

Do you know what the problem may be?

```
dat <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", na.strings="Not Available", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ha <- c("heart attack")

heart_attack_all <- if(outcome == ha) {
  ha_a <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat[, 2], ## hospital
                        dat[, 7], ## state
                        dat[, 11])) ## heart attack
colnames(ha_a) <- c("hospital name", "state", "outcome")
ha_a[, 3] <- as.numeric(ha_a[, 3])
return(ha_a) 
}
```

If you need the CSV file, it can be found [here.](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2FProgAssignment3-data.zip)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to combine `as.numeric` and `as.character` such as : `as.numeric(as.character())`

Comment: In order to provide a data sample, you may use `dput(dat)` .. and so those who will want to help you just have to copy and paste, without dealing with the csv files ...

Comment: @bVa, thanks! I will try this variant.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington, wow, thank you. I will use it from now. Should I run this first in my RStudio?

Comment: Also, what is `outcome`? It doesn't seem to be defined in the provided code, nor is it a column name of dat.

Comment: Yes, and you copy the result in your question ..

Comment: I believe the problem is with the construct `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`. First, `cbind` creates a matrix, that can only hold objects of one class and your numbers are coerced to something else. Try `ha_a <- data.frame(hospital = dat[, 2], state = dat[, 7], outcome = dat[, 11])`. Or even better, `ha_a <- dat[c(2, 7, 11)]`.

Comment: thank you everyone! I will try as soon as I get to my computer. <3

Comment: Maybe you can use ha_a[,3] <- apply(ha_a[,3], 1, as.numeric) (dont remember if its 1 or 2 to refer columns